# Help, I need advice for database design from SQLite to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have used SQLite in my current project, I have multiple sqlite databases.
db1) Database, one of which is users.
db2) Customer-specific local database, such as the customer's settings, the customer's accounts in the games, the changes made by the customer.
db3) My client program running on the client's computer, which I share some links with, takes some links from this database and performs the necessary operations. and
Customers' feedback is stored in a table in this database, all my customers can see each other's requests/complaints from my client program.

I want to design my system as mysql because I think it **would be better to use mysql instead of SQLite**, I have a few questions in my mind,

1. Should I open a database for each user and create a table for that user's private data and keep it in that database, or it will be very costly, is there another method, do you have a design suggestion that looks both useful and beautiful?

**I'm open to any suggestions, thank you for reading.**

**Note:** It is estimated that there will be 300 users at the moment, and there will be a maximum of 1000 users in 1-2 years.

Comment: This forum is litter with the question of whether to have multiple, identical, tables or dbs.  The answer is always "no".

Comment: @RickJames well then what is the best way? Create 3-4 tables for each user? Like user1_settings, user1_accounts_in_games, user1_changes etc.? Then this is not will be simple. (complex / I mean a lot tables for multiple users)

Comment: Will each user need access to his information and only his info?  Or is this some kind of 'game' with lots of 'users'?

Comment: In fact, the user will both have access to private information (tables) and anyone can access a table that I can edit. 
When the client is first opened, information about about 400 games will be sent from the server to each client (game name, game description, is it online, video link, etc.), generally reading.

Comment: "*I think it would be better to use mysql instead of SQLite*" - Why?

Answer (score 0):

Do not have multiple identical tables, unless you have serious security issues.

Even so, it may be possible to use Stored Procedures, Views, and/or GRANTs to control access.

There is a tradeoff between "login" security and programmatic security.  We need more details to help further.